# C# Best Practice to express a Kind of Object

Tags: c#

I'm building a Class to automate a external program using user32.dll on C#.

I got to a point that when I insert and submit a text (its an ID CODE) on a `TextBox`, some exceptions can be thrown and handled in form of a `MessageBox`, up until here, everything is okay.

This exceptions can be like "Printer Out Of Paper", "Invalid Code", etc...

## Here is the question:

If I have a method `GetErrorBox`, based on the Best Practices what should I return on this method?

```
public static bool GetErrorBox()
{
    // Test if ErrorBox Out Of Papper Exists
    if (CrossApplicationHandler.WindowExists("#####", "#######"))
        return ?;
    // Test if ErrorBox Invalid Code Exists
    else if (CrossApplicationHandler.WindowExists("#####", "#####"))
        return ?;
    else return ?; 
}
```

**EDIT**

I could return different `strings` and treat it on the caller, throw different `exceptions`, but I belive is clearer and the best way to do it, is returnin `Enum` like the user @Mabakay aswered.

Thank you guys, and sorry if I had some trouble trying to express myself on this question.

Here is the Solution:

```
public enum ErrorBox
{
    None = 0,
    OutOfPapper,
    InvalidCode,
    ...
}

public static ErrorBox GetErrorBox()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Huh?  Not sure I understand the question.

Comment: errr....a wild guess: maybe return `true` if the window exists, `false` if not?

Comment: well, based on your current return type you should be returning a `bool`...

Comment: If you name a method that begins with `Has` (or `Is` or `Does`, etc., etc.), I would expect the method to return `true` or `false` (a Boolean value).

Comment: An exception will never _be thrown in form of a messageBox_ It's (your?) code that eventually handles some excepion and show a MessageBox when it catches it. Your question is very unclear

Comment: @GianPaolo actually the external program handles the exception showing a MessageBox, sorry if that was not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on **The Best Practices** methods with prefix Has/Was/Is... should return bool. In your case you could use enum to return actual state of error box.

```
public enum ErrorBox
{
    None = 0,
    OutOfPapper,
    InvalidCode,
    ...
}

public static ErrorBox GetErrorBox()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: The problem when it comes to "best practices" is that it's entirely opinion based. _My_ best practice could be to always prefix methods with `m__` so I know it's a method. Someone else might have another system.

Comment: @gunr2171 Proving your point by saying "eww" to your practice. Unnecessary if your methods are verb-based and properties/variables are noun-based.

Comment: @itsme86 for the record, `m__` is just an example. The comment is trying to express the downfall of answering "best practice" questions in general.

Comment: That is what I was looking for, I belive using enum is the best way to do this. Thank You @Mabakay

Comment: @gunr2171 "Best practices" are based on opinion of most not individuals. You could understand it as form of standardization. "Someone else might have another system." thats right. But you could not call it "Best practices".